# Create a panel in google sheet to add an arbitrary number of rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I run into a google sheet file which has the panel reported in the image below at the bottom of every sheets. This panel allows the user to append an arbitrary number of rows to the last row of the sheets, in this way: insert the number of rows you want to add in the textbox then click on "Aggiungi altre" to add them.

[image]

Even though I'm a newbie in App Script, I know how to use a script to automate the addition of a static number of rows, but I really don't figure out how to create a panel similar to the one above and to connect the items to one another (the button to the textbox). I browse through some guides and tutorials but nothing seem to help me.

Can you give some hints?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of `mask` of `Create a mask to append an arbitrary number of rows on Google Sheet`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I tried to make my question clearer.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your updated question, do you want to add new rows using a dialog?

Comment: I don't want to use a dialog box but to understand how the google spreadsheet developer has inserted the panel I reported in the image. Since the spreadsheet is public I report you the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XmpLNjZo3lufdNdfaeY3U4waucGZ4M9WHWeKXNBcX0w/edit#gid=755788330) to open it, so that you can better understand what I mean

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I don't want to use a dialog box but to understand how the google spreadsheet developer has inserted the panel I reported in the image.` and your showing tags, if my understanding of your actual expected result, I'm worried that unfortunately, in the current stage, that cannot be achieved. But, if I misunderstood your actual expected result, I apologize.

Comment: As what @Tanaike mentioned, currently adding a custom UI similar to the image you showed is not an available feature that can be achieved using Apps Script.

Comment: Are you both saying that such implementation can not be developed anymore with the current App Script features? Or there is another way to built it up but with another google workspace tool?

Comment: Yes, as of now there are no methods to achieve the same UI using Apps Script or any Google Workspace tools. But I may suggest that you can submit a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) for it if in case they might deploy more UI Options for Apps Script if the feature you requested would have tons of votes / stars

Comment: I think that if such UI was available in the past and no more available today they are not going to endorse my proposal. Actually, my question was just for curiosity, but the same functionality can be obtained with nowadays (different) UI tools.